# I am having a issue with AsyncTask class

Tags: java, android, performance, android-asynctask, jsoup

My app crashes when the link is empty. I am trying to download Instagram videos. The apps work fine with public links. But I put a private link the app crashes. This means with a private link the apps get no HTML from the website. And the download links remain empty. Which causes the app to crash. I want when enter a private link app wouldn't crash

I tried to use if-else statements in the onPostExecute method but it didn't work or maybe I am doing it the wrong way.

This AsyncTask class

```
private class InstaVideo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String dlink, imglink;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            DoubleBounce doubleBounce = new DoubleBounce();
            progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(doubleBounce);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.10insta.net/#grid-gallery")
                        .data("url", temp)
                        .post();
                Log.v("Hello", doc.title());
                Element srctag = doc.select("img.card-img-top").first();
                Element ptag = doc.select("p.card-text").first();
                Element atag = ptag.select("a").first();
                imglink = srctag.attr("src");
                dlink = "https://www.10insta.net/";
                dlink += atag.attr("href");
                Log.i("DownloadActivity",dlink);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (dlink=="https://www.10insta.net/download.php?url=") {
                Toast.makeText(DownloadActivity.this,"Link is private",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                View loadingIndicator = findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);
                loadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imgtxt);
                if (Content.id == 2) {
                    t.setText("Video Preview");
                } else {
                    t.setText("Image Preview");
                }
                t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.instadownload);
                b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.instaimg);
                Picasso.get().load(imglink).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(img);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(dlink);
                        DownloadManager.Request req = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                        req.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                        if (Content.id == 2) {
                            req.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/VideoDownloader", "insta.mp4");
                        } else {
                            req.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/VideoDownloader", "insta.jpg");
                        }
                        StyleableToast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Download Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, R.style.mytoast).show();
                        Long ref = dm.enqueue(req);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

doInBackground fetch HTML from the website and filters the required video download link. This works fine with public links but crashes with private links. 
**Now I want when I enter a private link app wouldn't crash. help is much appreciated** 
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNAKl.png)

Comment: Because your `imglink` is null or empty, make sure you pass a valid path to picasso loader.

Comment: I already know it's empty that's what app is crashing. Tell me a way to prevent it

Comment: simple if block will prevent this if(validPath(imglink)){ Picasso.get().load(imglink).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(img); }

Comment: you are not getting my point

Comment: A private link needs authentication or token. You need to check instagram APIs (if available, i dont know) and check how you need to perform the required requests with the proper Authentication

Comment: If you're looking for a sampe implementation you might want to check out these projects: [instagram4j](https://github.com/brunocvcunha/instagram4j) or [jInstagram](https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have mentioned `if-else` not working to check image path then try to consume the exception using `try - catch` block.

```
try {
    Picasso.get().load(imglink).placeholder(R.drawable.loading).into(img);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    t.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**Besides this**, you use `==` operator to compare String which give you `false` always. Try using `equals()/equalsIgnoreCase()`

```
if (dlink.equalsIgnoreCase("https://www.10insta.net/download.php?url="))
```